# User profile sync with AD and custom provider

Tags: 2010, development, user-profile, web-services, bdc-model

This is kind of sequel for [question]: [How to bulk import User Profiles from a legacy system and pre-create MySites](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/13813/how-to-bulk-import-user-profiles-from-a-legacy-system-and-pre-create-mysites). After research I went with next strategy:

1. Part of users in new system will be
   UProfile synchronized via AD sync
   (this is ok and working)
2. Part of users which aren't in AD I would like to be be UProfile synchronized via BDC which will use custom profile provider (this is neccessary because they have some authentication system for internet users which MUST be used but which can provide us standard information about that kind of users).

Questions:

1. Is part 2 feasible (is it possible
   to do that)?
2. What should be steps for that part? (I assume that I should write custom provider and after that to create BDC WCF service which should use my custom profile provider to retrieve user informations from auth system, and after that to create BDC UP sync connection to my WCF service)? Is that right?
3. Any comment or maybe sceptical
   thought?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **can** do this, feasible or not. Check out my (former) colleagues answer [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/12000/need-to-sync-user-profile-with-aspnetdb-in-sharepoint-2010) on how to do this. Not sure about if BCS (BDC was the name in SP2007) would be possible, I know my colleague didnt use BCS fields so you would have to do a POC on that if you want to extract data from a secondary data source.

Another approach would be to create a flat file and do an [LDIF](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff959234.aspx) import.

Comment: Thank you again! Related to second approach (LDIF) - Wouldn't be necessary that customers authentication system suport LDAP? In our case it doesn't support. So I assume i must try with another approach. Why are you think that BCS wouldn't be oke to do that?

Comment: LDIF file is ment to be created by LDAP yes. Not sure, but I guess if you could create it externally (its just an text file) it would work. You would definately need to POC that though :-)